# SAML grant validity period

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I encountered a problem in using WSO2 SAML2 grant extension.

I want to set a **validity period** for the requested access token.

The default validity period is 3600, but in my application  I have users, whose session should not expire.

This can be done only by modifying the identity.xml file?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean -do you want to manage OAuth2 (Bearer) access token lifespan? It has nothing to do with the SAML assertion lifetime (which suppose to be short by design)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the access token expiry time, you can change the following value in `<API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml`

```
<UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>3800</UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>
```

Note: This will affect every access token generated by any grant type except for client-credentials grant type.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Working+with+Access+Tokens#WorkingwithAccessTokens-Changingthedefaulttokenexpirationtime